# Returning XML structures with SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Using the next SQL code, running with Oracle 10:

```
SELECT xmlserialize
    (
    document xmlelement
        (
        "Response", xmlforest
            (
            '00' AS "ReturnCode"
            ), xmlagg
            (
            xmlelement
                (
                "Students", xmlelement
                    (
                    "Student", xmlforest
                        (
                        'Some 1' AS "Name",
                        '1' AS "Id"
                        )
                    ), xmlelement
                    (
                    "Student", xmlforest
                        (
                        'Some 2' AS "Name",
                        '2' AS "Id"
                        )
                    )                                                                           
                ) 
            )                               
        ) AS CLOB INDENT
    ) FROM dual
```

... I get this XML structure:

```
<Response>
  <ReturnCode>00</ReturnCode>
  <Students>
    <Student>
      <Name>Some 1</Name>
      <Id>1</Id>
    </Student>
    <Student>
      <Name>Some 2</Name>
      <Id>2</Id>
    </Student>
  </Students>
</Response>
```

... but, I want to get this one (removing the 'root' element):

```
  <ReturnCode>00</ReturnCode>
  <Students>
    <Student>
      <Name>Some 1</Name>
      <Id>1</Id>
    </Student>
    <Student>
      <Name>Some 2</Name>
      <Id>2</Id>
    </Student>
  </Students>
```

Several attemps like this didnt work. Is mandatory to have a root element?:

```
SELECT xmlserialize
    (
    document xmlforest
        (
        '00' AS "ReturnCode"
        ), xmlagg
        (
        xmlelement
            (
            "Students", xmlelement
                (
                "Student", xmlforest
                    (
                    'Some 1' AS "Name",
                    '1' AS "Id"
                    )
                ), xmlelement
                (
                "Student", xmlforest
                    (
                    'Some 2' AS "Name",
                    '2' AS "Id"
                    )
                )                                                                           
            ) 
        ) AS CLOB INDENT
    ) FROM dual
```

Any help will be appreciated. (This is just a simplification of something more complex I need to do in some project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is why you need this? XML should be "Well Formed"
This means:
 - XML documents must have a root element
 - XML elements must have a closing tag
 - XML tags are case sensitive
 - XML elements must be properly nested
 - XML attribute values must be quoted

Add `extract('/*/*')` and change `document` -> `content`

```
SELECT xmlserialize
    (
    content xmlelement
        (
        "Response", xmlforest
            (
            '00' AS "ReturnCode"
            ), xmlagg
            (
            xmlelement
                (
                "Students", xmlelement
                    (
                    "Student", xmlforest
                        (
                        'Some 1' AS "Name",
                        '1' AS "Id"
                        )
                    ), xmlelement
                    (
                    "Student", xmlforest
                        (
                        'Some 2' AS "Name",
                        '2' AS "Id"
                        )
                    )                                                                           
                ) 
            )                               
        ).extract('/*/*') AS CLOB INDENT
    ) FROM dual
```

Comment: You can avoid calling `extract` by using `xmlconcat(...)` to generate a sequence of XML elements instead of wrapping them in `xmlelement("Response", ...)`. See my response at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866515/108326 for details.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest working way i could think is to use `replace`. See below:

```
Select replace(Replace(col,'< >',''),'</ >','') 
from 
(
SELECT xmlserialize
    (
    document xmlelement
        (
         " ", xmlforest --Putting a wide space to differentiate from other tags
            (
            '00' AS "ReturnCode"
            ), xmlagg
            (
            xmlelement
                (
                "Students", xmlelement
                    (
                    "Student", xmlforest
                        (
                        'Some 1' AS "Name",
                        '1' AS "Id"
                        )
                    ), xmlelement
                    (
                    "Student", xmlforest
                        (
                        'Some 2' AS "Name",
                        '2' AS "Id"
                        )
                    )                                                                           
                ) 
            )                               
        )
    )  AS COL
  FROM dual )
```

Output:

```
<ReturnCode>00</ReturnCode>
  <Students>
    <Student>
      <Name>Some 1</Name>
      <Id>1</Id>
    </Student>
    <Student>
      <Name>Some 2</Name>
      <Id>2</Id>
    </Student>
  </Students>
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9999/47)

Comment: No need for string manipulation of XML, just use `xmlserialize(content ...)` instead of `xmlserialize(document ...)`. See the other answers to this question for examples.

Comment: @markusk  There is no point answering same thing. What you answered is already been answered by someone and that's why you didnot get any votes. However by downvoting my answer you invited a downvote for repeatition of same answer.

Comment: My downvote was triggered by the use of string manipulation to modify XML (`replace`) instead of XML operations (`xmlconcat`, `extract`).

Comment: @markusk There was no need for downvoting. I just showed another way. As i hope you understand removing root anyways destroys the xml structure. Object was to just remove that and i achieved by simplest means. Its not necessary i do what you expect.

Comment: I consider string manipulation with `replace` to be strictly inferior, hence the downvote. Using a magic string like "wide space" (which is impossible to recognize or distinguish from normal whitespace in most user interfaces) seems hacky and harder to maintain.

Comment: @markusk There are always 10 ways to solve a problem. Some might be more elegant some might me hacky. I guess its up to OP to chose what actually suits his requirement. I guess you are unnecessarily trying to put your thoughts on my answer. OP already chose the answer which was bested suited for him. Try answering some other questions. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the root element means you will no longer have a valid XML structure, but rather a sequence of XML structures. You could construct this by using `xmlserialize(content ...)` instead of `xmlserialize(document ....)`.

```
SELECT xmlserialize(content xmlforest(
  '00' as "ReturnCode",
  xmlforest(
            xmlforest('Some 1' AS "Name",
                      '1' AS "Id"
                     ) AS "Student",
            xmlforest('Some 2' AS "Name",
                      '2' AS "Id"
                     ) AS "Student"
           ) AS "Students"
 ) AS CLOB INDENT)
FROM DUAL;
```

You could also use `xmlconcat` and `xmlelement` instead of `xmlforest`, if you prefer:

```
SELECT xmlserialize(content xmlconcat(
   xmlelement("ReturnCode", '00'),
   xmlelement("Students",
              xmlelement("Student",
                         xmlelement("Name", 'Some 1'),                                                            
                         xmlelement("Id", '1')
                        ),
              xmlelement("Student",
                         xmlelement("Name", 'Some 2'),
                         xmlelement("Id", '2')
                        ) 
             )
 ) AS CLOB INDENT)
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Isn't it the same what  @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz explained ..!! Why do you create repetition.

Comment: @XING My answer avoids the use of `extract`, and also demonstrates how to use `xmlconcat`.